# Problemas para actualizar un Reloj Digital cada segundo en Java

Tags: java, hilos, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy implementando un reloj en **Java** con la **IDE NetBeans** pero no actualiza los datos en tiempo real, solo repite los valores que toma:

**Clase *ClockThread***

```
package _class;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class ClockThread implements Runnable {

JLabel _Label;
Calendar time = new GregorianCalendar();
Date fechaHora = new Date();
int hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0;
String ampm;
Thread hiloClock;

public ClockThread(JLabel _Label) {
    this._Label = _Label;
    hiloClock = new Thread(this);
    hiloClock.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Thread _currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while (_currentThread == hiloClock) {
        _Label.setText(getDate());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClockThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}

    public String getDate() {
    String date = "";
    time.setTime(fechaHora);
    //Comparacion Ternaria : ?
    ampm = (Calendar.AM_PM) == 0 ? "AM" : "PM";
    hours = time.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minutes = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    seconds = time.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    System.out.println(seconds);
    date += hours;
    date += ":";
    date += minutes;
    date+=":";
    date += seconds;
    date += " ";
    date += ampm;

    return date;
}
```

}

El hilo anterior lo mando a llamar desde un `JFrame` con un evento `formWindowOpened`

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
   new ClockThread(lblClock);
}
```

> **Problema:** No actualiza el tiempo cada 1000 ms, solo muestra el primer valor obtenido;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es que al momento de que instancias tu clase **ClockThread** obtiene el valor de la fecha y el tiempo solamente en ese momento en estas lineas

```
Calendar time = new GregorianCalendar();
Date fechaHora = new Date();
```

Lo que creo pertinente seria solo crear los objetos y dejarlos null de esta manera

```
Calendar time;
Date fechaHora;
```

Y en el método **getDate()** instanciar estos objetos de tal modo que te quede de esta manera

```
  public String getDate() {
    time = new GregorianCalendar();
    fechaHora = new Date();

    String date = "";
    time.setTime(fechaHora);
    //Comparacion Ternaria : ?
    ampm = (Calendar.AM_PM) == 0 ? "AM" : "PM";
    hours = time.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minutes = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    seconds = time.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    System.out.println(seconds);
    date += hours;
    date += ":";
    date += minutes;
    date+=":";
    date += seconds;
    date += " ";
    date += ampm;

    return date;
  }
```

Así te aseguras de que el tiempo y la fecha obtenida sea cada vez que entra en el metodo **getDate()**